# for loop that replaces element based on its value

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a list of integers and I am trying to define a function which loops through every element to check if they are less than 5 and returns the list in string according to their contents.

```
intlist=[12, 10, 11, 23, 25, 2]

def clear(x):
    for i in x:
        if i < 5:
            x[i] = 0
        return str(x)
    else:
        return str(x)

print clear(intlist)
```

My code is not working as intended, could anyone enlighten me?

If they are, I am to change all elements in the list to '0'. The outcome should look something like this.

```
intlist=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However if none of the elements are less than 5, the output should remain the same.

```
intlist=[12, 10, 11, 23, 25, 2]
```

Comment: What's the error message?  As I can see in your code your indentations are not valid for `if-else` block.

Comment: What does string have anything to do with it?

Comment: i can't understand your question clearly,did you want to change the list element which less than 5 to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code has some logic problem. Here's my fix:

```
intlist=[12, 10, 11, 23, 25, 2]

def clear(x):
    for i in x:
        if i < 5:          # If this is satisfied once, return string with n times of '0'
            x = [0]*len(x) # This creates a list of zeros with same length as before
            return str(x)
    return str(x)

print clear(intlist)
```

Besides, in your example the element `2` is less than 5, so the output should be `000000`

Comment: thank you! this works but I would like to ask if an else statement is possible here?

Comment: @SamuelTan yeah it is possible but not necessary.

Comment: A break is however necessary. This only works because 2 is the last element.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's true, I just realized I am missing a return statement as I said in the comment, fixed.

Comment: Break is better if you want to avoid repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one one-line, creating a list of zeros if any one of the elements in list is less than `5` or retaining the list otherwise.

```
intlist = [12, 10, 11, 23, 25, 2]

intlist = [0] * len(intlist) if any(x < 5 for x in intlist) else intlist

print(intlist)
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Why filter the whole iterable when you can just do `any(x < 5 for x in intimate)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Yeah, that would be better. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
intlist=[12, 10, 11, 23, 25, 2]

def clear(x):
    if (any(i<5 for i in intlist)): return [0]*len(intlist)
    else: return(x)
print(clear(intlist)) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

check for the any item is <5 then return all zeros or keep the list as it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in the for loop that you have written. First, the return statement is inside the loop, which makes it exit just after the if statement or else statement, whichever it goes to first. Secondly, you are making a mistake with how you are indexing. If you wish to access elements through index, you range in your loop instead. Here is the correct implementation for the function that you want :

```
def clear(x):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]<5:
            x[i]=0

    return str(x)
```